# Who is the direct object and who is the indirect object

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, direct-objects, indirect-objects

In the following sentence, Who is the direct object and who is the indirect object?

> I know the woman in the blue dress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **direct object** is a noun or a noun phrase denoting a person or thing that is the recipient of the action of a transitive verb. For example, *the book* in *John gave the book to him* is a direct object because it is directly affected by the action of the transitive verb *gave*.

An **indirect object**, on the other hand, is a noun or a noun phrase referring to someone or something that is affected by the action of a transitive verb typically as a recipient, but is not the primary object. For instance, *him* in *John gave the book to him* is an indirect object because it is indirectly affected by the action of the transitive verb *gave*.

Applying all that knowledge to your example, we can see that there is only a direct object in your sentence which is represented by the noun phrase *the women in the blue dress* because *the women in the blue dress* is directly affected by the transitive verb *know*.